# Dealing with an error related to deleting a directory

Tags: error-handling, cascading-deletes

Following is a very simple program I wrote, using Visual Studio 2012, that clearly shows the error:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Using bmp As New Bitmap(800, 200)
            Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

            For n = 0 To 3
                Dim fileName As String = "D:\Users\Gerry\Desktop\TmpImages\SmileFace" + CStr(n) + ".jpg"
                Using tmpBmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Image.FromFile(fileName))
                    gr.DrawImage(tmpBmp, n * 200, 0)
                End Using
            Next
            gr.Dispose()

            Dim finalName As String = "D:\Users\Gerry\Desktop\Combined.jpg"
            bmp.Save(finalName, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End Using

        Directory.Delete("D:\Users\Gerry\Desktop\TmpImages", True)
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem, which happens both in debug and stand alone modes, is that the folder TmpImages does not get deleted. The following is the error text:

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file
> 'SmileFace0.jpg' because it is being used by another process. at
> System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath,
> Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound,
> WIN32_FIND_DATA& data) at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath,
> String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost) at
> Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectoryInternal(String
> directory, DeleteDirectoryOption onDirectoryNotEmpty, UIOptionInternal
> showUI, RecycleOption recycle, UICancelOption onUserCancel) at
> Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.FileSystemProxy.DeleteDirectory(String
> directory, DeleteDirectoryOption onDirectoryNotEmpty) at
> bmpSave.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
> C:\Users\Gerry\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Learning and
> Testing\bmpSave\bmpSave\Form1.vb:line 22 at
> System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

One experiment I tried was to add the statement Close after the statement gr.Dispose. The error is no longer thrown, but the directory is not deleted. Note that in the code, I tried both Directory.Delete and FileSystem.DeleteDirectory and had the same result both times. The error relates to one of the files in the folder TmpImages that is simply opened for reading.

Please suggest that which I should do to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Try putting a delay, either through a timer, or via `Sleep` prior to deleting the directory. Start with ten seconds. It might be that the file system is still finalizing some things when you're tryin to deleting the directory.

Comment: Good idea - didn't work...

Comment: I just tried a simple experiment: I deleted all lines of code except the last two lines: Directory.Delete and Application.Exit(). This time, the folder got deleted.